Core Data items in List view don't delete properly
In my app, I have a List view called LiftEventsView that displays lift events. Lift events are stored in Core Data as a LiftEvent.
When I swipe-to-delete a lift event, it doesn't immediately disappear from the list. The first time I swipe, the row remains visible, but the eventReps, eventWeight, and formattedOneRepMax values disappear. If I swipe a second time, the lift event is deleted.
One lift event in the list:

After the first swipe:

After the second swipe:

I'm learning SwiftUI from a Hacking with Swift+ tutorial and the relevant parts of my code are identical as far as I can tell. I've been debugging for 2 days, checking and rechecking the code, but can't figure it out.
struct LiftEventsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController

    let viewModel = LiftEventRowViewModel(calculator: Calculator())

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(dataController.liftEventsForSelectedFilter()) { liftEvent in
                LiftEventRow(liftEvent: liftEvent, viewModel: viewModel)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Lift Log")
    }

    func delete(_ offsets: IndexSet) {
        var events = dataController.liftEventsForSelectedFilter()

        Logger.liftEvents.debug(">>>User swiped to delete")
        Logger.coreData.debug("Events before deletion: \(events)")

        for offset in offsets {
            let item = events[offset]
            dataController.delete(item)
        }

        Logger.coreData.debug("Events after deletion: \(events)")
    }
}

struct LiftEventRow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @ObservedObject var liftEvent: LiftEvent

    let viewModel: LiftEventRowViewModel

    var calculator = Calculator()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(liftEvent.eventLocalizedLiftName)
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .semibold))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)

                Text("\(liftEvent.eventReps) reps @ \(liftEvent.eventWeight)" )
            }

            Spacer()

            VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                if let weight = Double(liftEvent.eventWeight),
                   let reps = Int(liftEvent.eventReps) {
                    let formattedOneRepMax = viewModel.formattedOneRepMax(weight: weight, reps: reps, formulaName: liftEvent.eventFormulaName)

                    Text(formattedOneRepMax)
                        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .semibold))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }

                Text(liftEvent.eventFormulaName)
            }
        }
    }
}

class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    @Published var selectedLiftEvent: LiftEvent?

    private var saveTask: Task<Void, Error>?

    // MARK: - Initialization

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {

        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "liftLog")

        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(filePath: "dev/null")
        }

        container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
            if let error {
                fatalError("Fatal error loading store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        let primer = CoreDataPrimer(managedObjectContext: self.container.viewContext)
        primer.seedCoreData()

        newLiftEvent()
    }

    func count<T>(for fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T>) -> Int {
        (try? container.viewContext.count(for: fetchRequest)) ?? 0
    }
    
    /// Creates a new LiftEvent and assigns it to @Published var selectedLiftEvent
    func newLiftEvent() {
        let liftEvent = LiftEvent(context: container.viewContext)
        liftEvent.uuid = NSUUID().uuidString
        liftEvent.date = .now
        liftEvent.formula = defaultFormula()
        liftEvent.lift = defaultLift()
        liftEvent.weightUnit = UserDefaults.unitsNotation().weightUnit


        self.selectedLiftEvent = liftEvent

        Logger.coreData.info("New lift event \(liftEvent.description) created")
        Logger.coreData.info("AFter new event created, selectedLiftEvent is \(self.selectedLiftEvent)")
    }

    /// Saves our Core Data context if there are changes. This silently ignores
    /// any errors caused by saving, but this should be fine because
    /// all our attributes are optional.
    func save() {
        saveTask?.cancel()

        if container.viewContext.hasChanges {
            try? container.viewContext.save()

            Logger.coreData.info("Context saved")
        }
    }

    func delete(_ object: NSManagedObject) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        container.viewContext.delete(object)
        save()

        Logger.coreData.debug("Deleted lift event \(object)")
    }

    func liftEventsForSelectedFilter() -> [LiftEvent] {
        let request = LiftEvent.fetchRequest()
        request.includesPendingChanges = false
        let allLiftEvents = (try? container.viewContext.fetch(request)) ?? []
        return allLiftEvents
    }

    func hasLiftEvents() -> Bool {
        var hasLiftEvents = false
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSNumber>(entityName: "LiftEvent")
        fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false
        fetchRequest.resultType = .countResultType

        do {
            let countResult = try container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            hasLiftEvents = countResult.first!.intValue > 0

            Logger.coreData.info("There are \(countResult) lift events in the log")
        } catch let error {
            Logger.coreData.info("Error checking for lift events: \(error)")

        }

        return hasLiftEvents
    }
}

extension LiftEvent {
    var eventID: String {
        uuid ?? ""
    }

    var eventCreationDate: Date {
        date ?? .now
    }

    var eventLift: Lift {
        if let lift = lift {
            return lift
        } else {
            if let context = self.managedObjectContext {
                let newLift = Lift(context: context)
                return newLift
            } else {
                fatalError("Managed Object Context is nil.")
            }
        }
    }

    var eventLiftName: String {
        get { lift?.liftName ?? "None" }
    }

    var eventLocalizedLiftName: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(eventLiftName, tableName: "liftLogModel", comment: "")
    }

    var eventFormulaName: String {
        formula?.formulaName ?? "None"
    }

    var eventReps: String {
        get {
            guard let reps = repetitions, reps.intValue != 0 else {
                return ""
            }
            return String(describing: reps)
        }
        set { repetitions = NSNumber(value: Double(newValue) ?? 0) }
    }

    var eventWeight: String {
        get {
            guard let weight = weightLifted, weight.intValue != 0 else {
                return ""
            }
            return String(describing: weight)
        }
        set { weightLifted = NSNumber(value: Double(newValue) ?? 0) }
    }

    var eventWeightUnit: WeightUnit {
        get {
            if let rawValue = weightUnit {
                return WeightUnit(rawValue: rawValue) ?? .kilograms
            }
            return .kilograms
        }
        set {
            weightUnit = newValue.rawValue
        }
    }
}

Log messages:

Context saved

There are [1] lift events in the log

>>>User swiped to delete

Events before deletion: [<LiftEvent: 0x600002129220> (entity: LiftEvent; id: 0x83602b006ad823c5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/LiftEvent/p33>; data: {
    date = "2024-05-16 17:43:07 +0000";
    formula = "0x83602b006e3823f5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/Formula/p6>";
    lift = "0x83602b006fb823e5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/Lift/p10>";
    repetitions = 3;
    uuid = "9B7F9CFA-1E3B-45E8-99B7-4D74A3428FD9";
    weightLifted = 205;
    weightUnit = kg;
})]

Context saved

Deleted lift event <LiftEvent: 0x600002129220> (entity: LiftEvent; id: 0x83602b006ad823c5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/LiftEvent/p33>; data: <fault>)

Events after deletion: [<LiftEvent: 0x600002129220> (entity: LiftEvent; id: 0x83602b006ad823c5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/LiftEvent/p33>; data: <fault>)]

There are [1] lift events in the log

>>>User swiped to delete

Events before deletion: [<LiftEvent: 0x60000213ee90> (entity: LiftEvent; id: 0x83602b006ab823c5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/LiftEvent/p34>; data: {
    date = "2024-05-16 17:43:14 +0000";
    formula = "0x83602b006e3823f5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/Formula/p6>";
    lift = "0x83602b006fb823e5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/Lift/p10>";
    repetitions = 0;
    uuid = "AFAB249F-0F14-4088-A46A-73A4060BCB4F";
    weightLifted = 0;
    weightUnit = kg;
})]

Context saved

Deleted lift event <LiftEvent: 0x60000213ee90> (entity: LiftEvent; id: 0x83602b006ab823c5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/LiftEvent/p34>; data: <fault>)

Events after deletion: [<LiftEvent: 0x60000213ee90> (entity: LiftEvent; id: 0x83602b006ab823c5 <x-coredata://DF552D0A-935D-4873-9114-CFB3C5CAAC8F/LiftEvent/p34>; data: <fault>)]

There are [0] lift events in the log


Your SwiftUI view isnt properly aware of the change i assume, because your ForEach iterates over func liftEventsForSelectedFilter() -> [LiftEvent] this function and creates a new FetchRequest everytime. Can you try using @FetchRequest instead in the view directly and see if that works?

I also thought the view isn't properly aware of the change but I don't think liftEventsForSelectedFilter() -> [LiftEvent] creates a new FetchRequest every time. I may be wrong but I think SwiftUI is smart enough to not do that when it updates the view. But I did try putting the @FetchRequest in a computed property but the behavior is still the same.
The odd thing is that the 1st swipe doesn't make the row disappear, but the values in the LiftEvent properties disappear. Then, the 2nd swipe makes the row disappear. So the view IS changing based on these actions, but in a very strange way.

I finally figured out what's causing this strange behavior.
When the app starts, a new lift event is created. Because it hasn't been saved at this point, it's marked as a temporary object. I have request.includesPendingChanges = false in my fetch request so temporary objects don't appear in the log.
When the user saves that lift event and new one is automatically created so they can perform another calculation. At this point, there is one saved lift event and the new temporary lift event in the context.
Then if I view the log and swipe to delete the saved lift event, it's deleted AND the context is saved. This save also saves the temporary lift event making it no longer temporary. So when the log view refreshes, this lift event now appears.
func delete(_ object: NSManagedObject) {
    objectWillChange.send()
    container.viewContext.delete(object)
        
    save()
}

The problem now is that if I remove save() from the delete function, the view doesn’t update and remove the deleted lift event.
